# Dynamic content display

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

when I select (say customer) using Dropdown I would want to show users all the properties on a side table or division.  Essentially, displaying the selected customer's fields on the same page for the users to verify/read.

I am using laravel-backpack for development and finding it difficult to implement.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there's no existing way to achieve that, you'd have to code it.

But you don't have to start from scratch, you can use the code for the `select2` field (or whatever field you prefer) and [create a new field type](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-fields#creating-a-custom-field-type), say `select2_and_preview` by tweaking the Javascript inside that one file.

There's recently been a Feature Request for a similar feature ([see here](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/2996)), you might want to pitch in with your opinion if you want it created by the team, and included in the official build.